# Transform SignalProducer that emits arrays to SignalProducer that emits all elements of the original array

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa

Let's say that I have a `SignalProducer<[Element], Error>` that emits an array of elements when started.

I would like to transform that `SignalProducer` to a new `SignalProducer<Element, Error>` that emits each element of the `[Element]` array consecutively.

What is the best approach to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
let firstProducer: SignalProducer<[Element], Error> = // something
let toSingleElement: [Element] -> SignalProducer<Element, Error> = { SignalProducer(values: $0) }

let secondProducer = firstProducer.flatMap(.Concat, transform: toSingleElement)
```

You can also use [Rex](https://github.com/neilpa/Rex)'s operator: [uncollect](https://github.com/neilpa/Rex/blob/master/Source/SignalProducer.swift#L139#L140).